# Roles and domain controllers - Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008

We have two windows server 08 machines, one of which is an AD slave to the other. Do the roles need to be mirrored if I was to say, add a printer role to one, or can they be kept fairly seperate in that respect?

Comment: Can you please edit your question, to clear up the bad terminology (slave) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea what you mean by "an AD slave to the other". If the two machines are both domain controllers (which is what I hope you mean), then no. They do not need to have the same roles, unless you're doing something with clustering or load-balancing. Which you probably shouldn't be doing with domain controllers.

Advice, not criticism - it sounds like you're admin-ing windows servers without knowing some really basic things about Windows and the ecosystem. If you're in the process of teaching yourself, then congrats, you're going to have a lot of fun. You should probably get the MS Press study guides for the MCITP Server Admin and Enterprise Admin. You don't even have to plan to take the test, but that's going to be a really cost-effective way to teach yourself about Server and AD, without making too many mistakes on actual servers.

Comment: Unfortunately I've inherited having to manage the windows domain without anyone else really knowing how the current setup was done. I'm trying to consolidate everything, moving the print server onto one of the DCs and set up a GPO for new employees.

Comment: Slow and steady, test everything, make sure you have an execution and  a backout plan for *everything*, take notes as you go (with clock times), and start teaching yourself. See if your company will pay to send you to MS class, because if you make a mistake in a small environment, you can really impact the whole company.

Comment: @MichaelThorpe, I would strongly reccomend having two domain controllers acting as domain controllers only - maybe have another server that acts as a file/print server but DCs should really only be used for one thing.

Comment: @MichaelThorpe before you go changing around the environment, it's perhaps best to assess the current situation and understand why things are the way they are before changing them.